# Shopping Cart Price Rule Not Working in magento 1.6.0

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento-1.6

I have a magento store running 1.6.0 and I cannot get a shopping cart price rule to work.
I have set below condition but this condition are not worked. I am not able to how to work below rule

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong as this is killing me... any input is appreciated.

Comment: In your conditions you have some categories listed in 'is one of' but in your actions you apply it only to a different category? is this category id in both? and you're asking for 'if quantity is below one' for the following in the condition part, seems backward?

Answer (score -1):

Your *Maximum Qty Discount is Applied* is set to zero (0), which means the promotion will never be applied to the cart. Try setting it to one (1) if you want this promotion to only apply one time in the cart.

Also, I do not know if the condition for applying the promotion is what you want because you have not given any detail on how the promotion should work. Write a few sentences telling us what conditions you want to be met and what the promotion should do when those conditions are met.